# Is there a way to evaluate JavaScript from within R?

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping

**Is there a way to evaluate JavaScript from within R?**

What I mean is there is any way that I can e.g. get access to content that is dynamically created within a web page via JavaScript? I am not talking about some clever workaround like to access raw data that JavaScript is getting from elsewhere.

**I suppose the answer is no** as all questions posed in this direction where solved by some indirect clever way **but I am not 100% sure.** Also I would feel enlightened if somebody could tell me why this is impossible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I thought that there wouldn't be, but I came across the [SpiderMonkey](http://www.omegahat.org/SpiderMonkey/) package which seems to do exactly that. It will be a pain to compile it in Windows, though.

---

I don't think the package has been released on CRAN. You'll have to install it straight from Omegahat repo. There are more details at the [Omegahat site](http://www.omegahat.org/).

Assuming that you have `Rffi` installed, which itself requires `libffi`, and the `bitops` package, you could just do this:

```
install.packages('SpiderMonkey', repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R",type='source')
```

If you're on Windows, you'll have to have Rtools installed and properly configured. Also, compiling `libffi` will be difficult, but Duncan Temple Lang indicates that he has been successful at least once (look in README.win in the `Rffi` source).